# using react-input-tag Can't resolve 'react-dnd' when running npm build

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to build my react application to prod but I get the following issue:
**ERROR in ./node_modules/react-tag-input/dist-modules/components/ReactTags.js 16:16-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dnd' in node_modules/react-tag-input/dist-modules/components**

I got no issue when using the package locallyin development environement but when I run npm run build I get this error.

Here is my dependencies from package.json

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@aws-amplify/auth": "^4.5.9",
        "@aws-amplify/core": "^4.5.9",
        "@casl/ability": "^6.3.3",
        "@casl/react": "^3.1.0",
        "ag-grid-community": "^28.2.1",
        "ag-grid-react": "^28.2.1",
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "flag-icons": "^6.6.6",
        "process": "^0.11.10",
        "react": "^18.1.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
        "react-datepicker": "^4.8.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
        "react-flags-select": "^2.2.3",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
        "react-intl": "^6.0.4",
        "react-query": "^3.39.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
        "react-select": "^5.4.0",
        "react-tag-input": "^6.8.1"
    }
```

Here is my wepback config file:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");


const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'PRD';

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve("./dist"),
        publicPath: "/",
    },
    module: {
        rules:[
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: "babel-loader"
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use:["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpg|png|ico|pdf)$/,
            type: "asset/inline",
        }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: 'process/browser'
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(envVariables),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            filename: "index.html",
            template: "./public/index.html",
            favicon: "./public/favicon.ico"
        })
    ],
    devtool: dev ? 'cheap-module-source-map' : 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        static: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
        historyApiFallback: { index: "/", disableDotRule: true },
        hot: true,
        port: 3000,
  },
}
```

I don't know why the issue appears only in prod env

I tried to change react-tag-input package version
I tried also to add this rule in my webpack config file:

```
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.join(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
        alias: {
            react: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react'),
        },
        fallback: {
            'react/jsx-runtime': 'react/jsx-runtime.js',
            'react/jsx-dev-runtime': 'react/jsx-dev-runtime.js',
        }
    }
```